# Move a UIImage inside of CGRect using animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

So I'm trying to figure out how to move UIImages that are drawn inside a CGRect up a cell on the screen using animateWithDuration, but I'm having trouble visualizing where to write the code as well as how to write it for a UIImage.  I have an array of CGRects with content the UIImage drawn inside of it, and I want to move all of the images at the same time.  Once they get to the top most cell, I want them to then appear in the bottom cell and start again.  Here is a picture to get a better idea of what I'm talking about:

[DragMeToHell Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH8v5.png)

And here's my drawRect code for the UIView and UIImages:

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        print( "drawRect:" )

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!  // obtain graphics context
    // CGContextScaleCTM( context, 0.5, 0.5 )  // shrink into upper left quadrant
    let bounds = self.bounds          // get view's location and size
    let w = CGRectGetWidth( bounds )   // w = width of view (in points)
    let h = CGRectGetHeight( bounds ) // h = height of view (in points)
    self.dw = w/10.0                      // dw = width of cell (in points)
    self.dh = h/10.0                      // dh = height of cell (in points)

    print( "view (width,height) = (\(w),\(h))" )
    print( "cell (width,height) = (\(self.dw),\(self.dh))" )

    // draw lines to form a 10x10 cell grid
    CGContextBeginPath( context )               // begin collecting drawing operations
    for i in 1..<10 {
        // draw horizontal grid line
        let iF = CGFloat(i)
        CGContextMoveToPoint( context, 0, iF*(self.dh) )
        CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, w, iF*self.dh )
    }
    for i in 1..<10 {
        // draw vertical grid line
        let iFlt = CGFloat(i)
        CGContextMoveToPoint( context, iFlt*self.dw, 0 )
        CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, iFlt*self.dw, h )
    }
    UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()                        // use gray as stroke color
    CGContextDrawPath( context, CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke ) // execute collected drawing ops

    // establish bounding box for image
    let tl = self.inMotion ? CGPointMake( self.x, self.y )
                           : CGPointMake( CGFloat(row)*self.dw, CGFloat(col)*self.dh )
    let imageRect = CGRectMake(tl.x, tl.y, self.dw, self.dh)

    // place images in random cells
    //cellCoordinates = self.generateCoordinates()
    for xy in cellCoordinates {
        let randomImageRect = CGRectMake(xy.x, xy.y, self.dw, self.dh)
        let lavaImage : UIImage? = UIImage(named: "lava.png")
        lavaImage!.drawInRect(randomImageRect)
        imageCells.append(randomImageRect)
    }

    // place appropriate image where dragging stopped [EDITED]
    var img : UIImage?
    if ( self.col == 9 ) {
        img = UIImage(named:"otto.png")
    } else {
        img = UIImage(named:"angel.png")
    }
    img!.drawInRect(imageRect)

    // check for image intersection
    for tempImageRect in imageCells {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageRect, tempImageRect)) {
            img = UIImage(named:"devil.png")
            img!.drawInRect(imageRect)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `drawRect` instead of a collection view or a bunch of image views? The latter approaches would make animation much simpler.

Comment: @AaronBrager wouldn't using a CGRect the size of a cell and fitting the image inside of it be the best way to place it into a cell? CGRect also made collision detection easier too

Comment: A `CGRect` is just a struct that represents the size and position of something rectangular. So you can still use collusion detection with views by looking at `view.frame` which is a `CGRect`. No need to draw stuff like you're doing. Just use `UIImageView` for images and regular `UIView` for the lines.

Comment: @AaronBrager so just to clarify, change the array from an array of CGRects to an array of UIImageViews? And then that makes animation easier I'm assuming. Also, where would I write the code to get the images to move every 3 seconds let's say?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you delete your entire `drawRect` function and use normal views instead of drawing them manually.

Comment: @AaronBrager only problem with that is this is an assignment where we have to build on the code that was provided, which drawRect was one of those functions provided. I already implemented the images, the next part was animations. That's what is making it difficult